# Mobile Router with automatic APN setting

Tags: router, wireless, networking, mobile-phone, 4g

I am looking for a Mobile Router Hotspot.  Something similar to like a Netgear Nightawk M1 Mobile Router (MR1100) that is not branded by a carrier like Verizon or ATT or others.  Something I can purchase directly through the manufacturer and place a SIM in it to use in USA and Europe.

In fact I really like that Netgear Nighthawk M1 Mobile Router (MR1100), except for the fact that I have to go and change the APN settings every time I change the SIM card.

For mobile phones like iPhone, setting up APN is not required.  You just put in the SIM card and everything works.

I am willing to write software that sets up the connection based on carrier, but I would need Netgear to give me access to the internals and source code, which is not possible to my knowledge.

Can anyone recommend a Mobile Router Hotspot that is similar, but APN settings automatic.